# cannot create project netbeans 6.*

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this error creating a new project on netbeans 6.10M (on 25% of project creation), on other versions, the creation of a new project just fails.. some other functionalities of netbeans are also not working..
im using Snow Leopard, last version

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
 at org.netbeans.modules.project.ant.ProjectXMLCatalogReader.projectXmlCombinedSchema(ProjectXMLCatalogReader.java:189)
 at org.netbeans.modules.project.ant.ProjectXMLCatalogReader.validate(ProjectXMLCatalogReader.java:154)
 at org.netbeans.modules.project.ant.AntBasedProjectFactorySingleton.loadProjectXml(AntBasedProjectFactorySingleton.java:384)
 at org.netbeans.modules.project.ant.AntBasedProjectFactorySingleton.loadProject(AntBasedProjectFactorySingleton.java:237)
 at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager.createProject(ProjectManager.java:361)
 at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager.access$300(ProjectManager.java:85)
 at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager$2.run(ProjectManager.java:282)
 at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager$2.run(ProjectManager.java:233)
 at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:330)
 at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager.findProject(ProjectManager.java:233)
 at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectGenerator$1.run(ProjectGenerator.java:190)
 at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectGenerator$1.run(ProjectGenerator.java:120)
 at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:436)
 at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectGenerator.createProject0(ProjectGenerator.java:120)
 at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectGenerator.createProject(ProjectGenerator.java:114)
 at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProjectGenerator.createProject(J2SEProjectGenerator.java:235)
 at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProjectGenerator.access$000(J2SEProjectGenerator.java:87)
 at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProjectGenerator$1.run(J2SEProjectGenerator.java:108)
 at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(EventControl.java:125)
 at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(FileSystem.java:566)
 at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProjectGenerator.createProject(J2SEProjectGenerator.java:106)
 at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.ui.wizards.NewJ2SEProjectWizardIterator.instantiate(NewJ2SEProjectWizardIterator.java:185)
 at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1019)
 at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:591)
 at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:412)
 at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:256)
 at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:168)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1541)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1498)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1700(WizardDescriptor.java:130)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2069)
 at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1426)
 at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1968)
Caused: org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem: task failed due to
 at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor.post(RequestProcessor.java:421)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2115)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$8.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1430)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.lazyValidate(WizardDescriptor.java:1470)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1300(WizardDescriptor.java:130)
 at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.actionPerformed(WizardDescriptor.java:2125)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.invoke(WeakListenerImpl.java:459)
 at $Proxy14.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6348)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6113)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4714)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
[catch] at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:635)
 at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:137)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
 at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1046)
 at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1098)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1096)
 at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:1006)
 at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1040)
 at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1028)
 at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:121)
 at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1361)
 at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:271)
 at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:1013)
 at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1563)
 at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1515)
 at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:842)
 at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:986)
 at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateImpl(TemplateWizard.java:498)
 at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:365)
 at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.NewProject$2.run(NewProject.java:139)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:633)
 at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:137)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Please comment on my answer.  If you have already got the solution update this question.  If you are still struggling with this issue and not satisfied with my answer tell me what works and what not so I may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 6.9 works nicely here on 10.6.

I would uninstall everything related to Netbeans (throw the installed folders in the Trash and empty it), and then install *just* 6.9 again.

Comment: i fixed it, just removed xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar from *java home*/lib/ext

Comment: How did THAT end up there?  Stay away from ext.

Answer (score 0):

1. NetBeans IDE 6.10M1 is not a stable version of NetBeans IDE, this version is released for early access by the community to test it and report bugs to the NetBeans Development team through the NetBeans Issue system.  If you have found a bug you should file a bug report and help the developers identify scenarios which they may fix eventually.  By old versions do you mean any version before 6.10M1?

   2. If you want to use NetBeans IDE for production you should use the latest stable version of NetBeans IDE that is NetBeans IDE 6.9.1.  I am using Snow Leopard on MacBook pro and I am able to create Java Projects as well as NetBeans Platform Project.
   3. Please elaborate your project scenario so more detailed answer can be written.  Many a times just deleting the user directory $HOME/.netbeans help in fixing configuration issues

Hope this helps

with regards
Tushar